# java List with all combinations of 8 booleans

Tags: java, boolean, subset, combinations

Let's say I pass in 3 trues and 5 falses, how can I code the `getAllCombos` method to return a List that includes:

- A 1 `SampleForSO` object with the 3 chosen
- The 3 "Three Choose Two" combinations
- The 3 "Three Choose One" combinations
- The 1 `SampleForSO` object with none chosen

So I'd return a List with:

- SampleForSO(T, T, T, F, F, F, F, F)
- SampleForSO(T, T, F, F, F, F, F, F)
- SampleForSO(T, F, T, F, F, F, F, F)
- SampleForSO(F, T, T, F, F, F, F, F)
- SampleForSO(T, T, F, F, F, F, F, F)
- SampleForSO(F, T, T, F, F, F, F, F)
- SampleForSO(T, F, T, F, F, F, F, F)
- SampleForSO(F, F, F, F, F, F, F, F)

---

public class SampleForSO {

```
private boolean b0;
private boolean b1;
private boolean b2;
private boolean b3;
private boolean b4;
private boolean b5;
private boolean b6;
private boolean b7;

public SampleForSO(boolean b0, boolean b1, boolean b2, boolean b3, boolean b4, boolean b5, boolean b6, boolean b7) {
    this.b0 = b0;
    this.b1 = b1;
    this.b2 = b2;
    this.b3 = b3;
    this.b4 = b4;
    this.b5 = b5;
    this.b6 = b6;
    this.b7 = b7;
}

public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if(o instanceof SampleForSO) {
        SampleForSO outer = (SampleForSO) o;
        return outer.b0 == this.b0 && outer.b1 == this.b1 && outer.b2 == this.b2 && outer.b3 == this.b3 && outer.b4 == this.b4 && outer.b5 == this.b5 && outer.b6 == this.b6 && outer.b7 == this.b7;
    }
    return false;
    
}

public static List<SampleForSO> getAllCombos(boolean b0, boolean b1, boolean b2, boolean b3, boolean b4, boolean b5, boolean b6, boolean b7){
    // How to get all the combos?
    return new ArrayList<SampleForSO>();
}
```

}

---

Here's a JUnit test that would show green if that method worked:

---

```
public class SampleForSOTest {

    public SampleForSOTest() {
        super();
    }
    
    @Test
    public void testGetAllCombinations() throws Exception {
        
        // 3 true, 5 false, but need this to work for all possibilities
        boolean b0_ = true;
        boolean b1_ = true;
        boolean b2_ = true;
        boolean b3_ = false;
        boolean b4_ = false;
        boolean b5_ = false;
        boolean b6_ = false;
        boolean b7_ = false;

        int numCombosWithAllThree = 1;
        int numCombosWithTwo = 3;
        int numCombosWithOne = 3;
        int numCombosWithZero = 1;

        int expectedSize = numCombosWithAllThree + numCombosWithTwo + numCombosWithOne + numCombosWithZero;
        
        List<SampleForSO> allCombos = SampleForSO.getAllCombos(b0_, b1_, b2_, b3_, b4_, b5_, b6_, b7_);

        assertEquals(expectedSize, allCombos.size());
    }

    

}
```

The combos I'd want would be:

- b0, b1, b2 all true, all else false
- b0 b1 true, all else false
- b1 b2 true, all else false
- b2 b0 true, all else false
- b0 true, all else false
- b1 true, all else false
- b2 true, all else false
- all false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following Code generates all combinations

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

  public static List<List<Boolean>> generateAllCombinations(List<Boolean> input) {
    var combinations = new ArrayList<List<Boolean>>();
    if (input.isEmpty()) {
      return combinations;
    }

    // add combination seed
    combinations.add(new ArrayList<>());
    for (var inputIndexValue : input) {
      var nextCombinations= new ArrayList<List<Boolean>>();

      for (var indexCombination : combinations) {
          
        if (inputIndexValue) {
           // true is only valid if inputIndexValue is true
          var newCombination = new ArrayList<>(indexCombination);
          newCombination.add(true);
          nextCombinations.add(newCombination);
        }
        
        // false is always a valid value
        var newCombination = new ArrayList<>(indexCombination);
        newCombination.add(false);
        nextCombinations.add(newCombination);
      }

      combinations = nextCombinations;
    }

    return combinations;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    var input = List.of(true, true, true, false, false, false, false, false);
    var allCombinations = generateAllCombinations(input);
    for (var combination : allCombinations) {
      System.out.println(combination);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another completely different alternative is to just treat the `true` values as bits directly, incrementing in binary.  To avoid iterating over the entire list each time, an array of the indices of the true values is obtained.

```
List<List<Boolean>> combos = new ArrayList<>();

List<Boolean> values = new
         ArrayList<>(List.of(true, false, true, false, true));
     
int[] indices = IntStream.range(0, values.size())
            .filter(i -> values.get(i)).toArray(); // [0, 2, 4] for example
```

`values` changes each time so it must be resubmitted as is changed to continue the next iteration.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1 << indices.length; i++) {
            combos.add(increment(indices, values));
}

combos.foreach(System.out::println);
```

in this example, prints

```
[false, false, false, false, false]
[false, false, false, false, true]
[false, false, true, false, false]
[false, false, true, false, true]
[true, false, false, false, false]
[true, false, false, false, true]
[true, false, true, false, false]
[true, false, true, false, true]
```

The increment method

```
public static List<Boolean> increment(int indices[], List<Boolean> values) {
    for (int i = indices.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (!values.get(indices[i])) {
            values.set(indices[i], true);
            return new ArrayList<>(values);
        } else {
            values.set(indices[i], false);
        }
    }
    return new ArrayList<>(values);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach to this was to treat the list of `booleans` as `1's` and `0's` packed into a byte.  So `true,true,false` would be `110`.

It should also be noted that the number if `n` is the number of `true` values in the original list, then the number of combinations that actually contain a `true` boolean is **2<sup>n</sup>-1**.  Adding an additional combination takes care of the combinations containing only `false` values.

Ideally, one would like to increment across all non-consecutive one bits as though they were contiguous. For example, consider `1101`.  The low order second bit is ignored.

```
0000
0001
0100
0101
1000
1001
1100
1101
```

This is easily done by making use of the methods [Integer.expand](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#expand(int,int)) and [Integer.compress](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#compress(int,int)) introduced in Java 19.  By specifying a bit mask of the `1` bit's current positions, they can be `compressed` to the low order position as a single stream of `1` bits. This can be reversed by using `expand` to put them back.

Example:

```
int a = 0b101010;
int mask = 052;  // octal
int compress = Integer.compress(a,mask);
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(compress)); //0111;
int expand = Integer.expand(compress,mask);
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(expand)); //101010
```

To allow this to work with I added the following constants.

```
static int NBITS = 8;
static int HIGHBITMASK = 1<<(NBITS-1); // x80 for 8 bits
static int ALLBITMASK = (1<<NBITS)-1;  // xFF for 8 bits
```

Additional, I created some helper lambdas to pack and unpack the `booleans` to and from an `int`.

```
static Function<Integer, List<Boolean>> unpack = a -> {
    List<Boolean> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < NBITS; i++) {
        list.add((a & HIGHBITMASK) == HIGHBITMASK);
        a <<= 1;
    }
    return list;
};

static Function<List<Boolean>, Integer> pack = list -> 
    list.stream().mapToInt(a -> a ? 1 : 0).reduce(0,
            (a, b) -> a << 1 | b);
```

Here is the working `generateCombinations()` method.

```
public static List<List<Boolean>> generateCombinations(List<Boolean> list) {
    // not certain how you wish to handle null or empty
    // submission but here is one way.
    if (list == null || list.isEmpty()) {
            return new ArrayList<List<Boolean>>();
    }

    int mask = pack.apply(list);
    int nCombos = Integer.compress(ALLBITMASK, mask) + 1;
    List<List<Boolean>> combos = IntStream.range(0, nCombos)
            .mapToObj(c -> unpack.apply(Integer.expand(c, mask))).toList();
    return combos;
}
```

**Other stuff**

If you want to see the frequency count of various combinations, you can do this (using your original list) where the `key/value` pairs show the number count of true values (key) and the number of combinations which had that count (value).

```
List<List<Boolean>> combos = generateCombinations(list);

Map<Integer, Long>  map = combos.stream().mapToInt(pack::apply).boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Integer::bitCount, Collectors.counting()));

map.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints

```
0=1
1=3
2=3
3=1
```

Note that the counts follow Pascal's triangle.

To make your class more versatile, you can change the constructor to use the `varargs` operator.

```
public SampleForSO(Boolean... bArray) {
    this.bArray = bArray; // 
}
```

`bArray` will be an array containing the number of elements passed.  Then you can check for equality in your equals method by doing `Arrays.equals(bArray, this.bArray);`

But of course, this depends on your use case since you would have to access the `booleans` via an array index.

Comment: WJS - the implementation I was replacing had used a bit strategy but it stopped working once it got to 8 bits, do you think this would work for 12 bits?

Comment: Yes.  I can modify it and let you check it out.But remember that if all true were submitted you would then return 4096 combinations.

Comment: nice, I'll probably use the more-lines-but-more-readable, but I like the bit strategy too

Comment: I have a few more suggestions I'll add.

Comment: I modified the code.  Setting `NBITS` to the number of bits allows flexibility.  All masks are based on that.  If you have any questions let me know.  Hope this helps.